# WooCommerce: Rename, add and remove email templates in the order dropdown send email widget

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

A few days ago I've asked a question how to rename the email templates in WooCommerce. Luckily a good member from Stackoverflow helped me with his answer.

After going to the order overview I saw that the templates in the dropdown where I can sent emails manually are not renamed as you can see in the picture below:

[image]

So to ask a full qualified question: How can I rename, add and remove email templates in this dropdown?

**UPDATE**

I've found the code where the widget is created but I don't know how to hook in there to rename or add emails:

```
/**
     * Resend order emails
     */
    public function send_order_email_meta_box( $post ) {
        ?>
        <ul class="wpo_wcpdf_send_emails submitbox">
            <li class="wide" id="actions">
                <select name="wpo_wcpdf_send_emails">
                    <option value=""></option>
                    <?php
                    $mailer           = WC()->mailer();
                    $available_emails = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_resend_order_emails_available', array( 'new_order', 'cancelled_order', 'customer_processing_order', 'customer_completed_order', 'customer_invoice' ) );
                    $mails            = $mailer->get_emails();
                    if ( ! empty( $mails ) && ! empty( $available_emails ) ) { ?>
                        <?php
                        foreach ( $mails as $mail ) {
                            if ( in_array( $mail->id, $available_emails ) && 'no' !== $mail->enabled ) {
                                echo '<option value="send_email_' . esc_attr( $mail->id ) . '">' . esc_html( $mail->title ) . '</option>';
                            }
                        } ?>
                        <?php
                    }
                    ?>
                </select>
                <input type="submit" class="button save_order button-primary" name="save" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Save order & send email', 'woocommerce-pdf-invoices-packing-slips' ); ?>" />
                <?php
                $title = __( 'Send email', 'woocommerce-pdf-invoices-packing-slips' );
                $url = wp_nonce_url( add_query_arg('wpo_wcpdf_action','resend_email'), 'generate_wpo_wcpdf' );
                // printf('<a href="%s" class="button wpo_wcpdf_send_email"><span>%s</span></a>')
                ?>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <?php
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Soooo I've tried a lot and found the solution:

```
/**
 * Change array which adds the widget in each order for sending emails
 */
add_filter( 'woocommerce_resend_order_emails_available', 'change_emails_to_send', 10, 1 );
function change_emails_to_send() {
    return array( 'new_order', 'cancelled_order', 'customer_processing_order', 'customer_completed_order' );
}
```

You can add, or remove emails now. I'm not sure how I can rename it but I hope I find it out.